# Pyproj distance between points and between a point and polygon

Tags: polygon, distance, spatial, point-in-polygon, pyproj

I want to calculate projected distance between two points and between a point a polygon. All coordinates are specified under same projection lat,lon (WGS84).

I calculated the distance between a point and a polygon using pyproj as follows:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform, Geod
geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
angle1,angle2,dist1 = geod.inv(wLong1, sLat1, wLong2, sLat2)
#this returns distance in m
```

I want to use the same function to calculate the distance between a point and a bounding box.

```
bbox = box(wLong1, sLat1, eLong1, nLat1)
point = Point(wLong2,sLat2)
dist2 = (point.distance(bbox))
```

Unlike the first example (dist1 in meter), I think the second example (dist2) returns distance in degrees. How can I translate this value into meter like example 1?

Comment: Did you try my code? If you still have further question, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need mean radius of earth's curvature (rm) for computation.

```
from pyproj import Geod
from math import radians

# ... some code

a = Geod.a
b = Geod.b
rm = (2.0*a + b)/3.0   # simple mean radius, as defined by IUGG
rm * radians(dist2)    # your dist in meters
```

More accurate formulas for rm exist, but the above is good approximate.